# Kiwi TCMS Network Setup on AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, kiwi-tcms

Followed the setup guide with a digital ocean Ubuntu droplet without a hitch. 
Tried the same guide with an AWS Instance and can't get served any pages through the browser.

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html

I know AWS uses a different networking setup, but I'm not sure where or what settings / files I need to change to get it working. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure your EC2 instance or Container instance has its security group configured to allow http/https traffic ?

Comment: That's so weird and now I feel stupid! 

So I thought I had before when trying a few months ago, and our IT Admin couldn't figure it out on his own.

Checking now http/https did not have rules set in the security group. Adding them worked! Thank you very much!